# Multiplying unknown variable factorials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

How is it that $k!(k+1)$ can be simplified to $(k + 1)!$ ? 
$(k(k!) + k!)$ seems intuitive enough, but where do you go from there?

Comment: By definition $\,(k+1)!= (k+1) \,k \, (k-1) \,\cdots\,1=(k+1) \cdot \Big(\,k \, (k-1) \,\cdots\,1\,\Big) = (k+1)\cdot k!\,$.

Answer (score 1):

Just as divx showed, it follows directly from the definition. ..the only factor in $(k+1)! $ that is missing from $k! $ is $(k+1)$.